# What should I pass to controller in order to perform model unit testing in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

How to perform model unit testing in .net core 2.0? I am not getting what to pass to Homecontroller class in unit testing class. This is my unit testing class where I need help

[image]

```
using BasicUnitTesting.Models;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using BasicUnitTesting.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace BasicUnitTestProj
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void GetEmployeeTest()
        {
            HomeController home = new HomeController(null); //What should i pass to HomeController

            var vr = home.GetEmployee() as ViewResult;

            List<Employee> expectedemps = new List<Employee>()
            {
                new Employee() {EmpID=101,EmpName="Abhilash",Salary=50000},
                new Employee() {EmpID=102,EmpName="Abhishek",Salary=60000},
                new Employee() {EmpID=103,EmpName="Nagraj",Salary=30000},
                new Employee() {EmpID=104,EmpName="Sunil",Salary=50000},
                new Employee() {EmpID=105,EmpName="Vinay",Salary=40000}
            };

            Assert.IsTrue(expectedemps.SequenceEqual(vr.Model as List<Employee>));
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my Homecontroller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using BasicUnitTesting.Models;

namespace BasicUnitTesting.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly CompanyDbContext _context

        public HomeController(CompanyDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }

        public IActionResult GetEmployee()
        {
            //CompanyDbContext Db = new CompanyDbContext();
            //List<Employee> emps = Db.Employees.ToList();
            List<Employee> emps = _context.Employees.ToList();
            return View(emps);
        }         
    }
}
```

My model and Context class are as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace BasicUnitTesting.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmpID { get; set; }
        public string EmpName { get; set; }
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    }

    public class CompanyDbContext:DbContext
    {
        public CompanyDbContext()
        {
        }

        public CompanyDbContext(DbContextOptions<CompanyDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass abstraction/interface to your Controller, it should not know about details/implementation of your DbContext.

What you need is another Interface/Contract:

```
public interface ICompanyDbContext
{
   DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

and your class should implement this interface:

```
public class CompanyDbContext: ICompanyDbContext, DbContext
```

Your controller should have argument of ICompanyDbContext not CompanyDbContext:

```
public HomeController(ICompanyDbContext context)
```

This allows you to mock ICompanyDbContext in your unit test:

```
var dbContext = new Mock<ICompanyDbContext>();
// you should SetUp mock as well as do verification on it

HomeController home = new HomeController(dbContext.Object);
```

Comment: I am getting "The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item" in ICompanyDbContext interface

Comment: I've removed it, copy/paste. Interface will always have implicitly public accessor.

Comment: I would change as well DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; } to List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }. In the DbSet is more tied up to DbContext implementation of you interface. In the future you might want to get your data from file, memory, NHibernate and it does not make sense to return DbSet.